# How to generate assets for a mobile UI from Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, png, interface-design, mobile

Currently, I'm using Photoshop to design a mobile UI and I use PNG Express to generate assets for various size and devices. I want to know if there is any such supporting tool for Illustrator to generate assets if we design in it.

Comment: Hi, I recommend you to use a more appropriate tool to make UI. I suggest you Sketch App or keep using Photoshop. Exporting assets from illustrator is a bit harder.

With Sketch you can export your assets easily and you can work with vectors.

Comment: Hi sureshkumar, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this famous extension made for Illustrator.

[Layer Exporter for Illustrator](https://github.com/davidderaedt/Illustrator-Layer-Exporter)

PS:
I recommend you to use a more appropriate tool to make UI. I suggest you Sketch App or keep using Photoshop. Exporting assets from illustrator is a bit harder. With Sketch you can export your assets easily and you can work with vectors and symbols.

Comment: Or if you're using illustrator cs6, you might find Thomas Byrne's script useful.  (http://www.tbyrne.org/export-illustrator-layers-to-svg-files)